# Cross Platform Installer

Tags: cross-platform

Our C++/QT desktop application for Mac, Windows and Linux needs an installer. I'd rather we have a single installer for all three platforms. I do know it's a bit tricky, I guess what I wanted ask is if a framework already exists for that (Java maybe?).

I'd really like to avoid having to write three different installers.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Installer-Framework

Answer (score 11):

The link that Kyle mentions is pretty comprehensive, but I wanted to provide a bit more of information about [InstallBuilder for Qt](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/qt-developers.html)  (Disclaimer, I am one of the developers) since most of the cross platform installation programs referenced there are Java-based. This requires bundling a JRE, etc. and adds a significant overhead that is not required with a Qt-based installer, like ours.  It is able to generate wizard-like executable installers for all platforms from a single project file as well as native packages such as DEB and RPM. If you ship your software in DVDs, you can create a single multi-platform DVD that shares data across platforms but still have native launchers.

Having said this, since your application is Desktop-oriented, for the particular case of OS X if it does not require complex installation you may be better off creating a .app file and package it inside a DMG. Users can then drag the file directly to the Applications folder.

Finally, I wanted to mention that InstallBuilder is commercial, but we offer free licenses for open source projects and discounts for small development firms.

Answer (score 3):

IzPack rocks: http://izpack.org. It is truly crossplatform, very lightweight, easy to master, and produces excellent results.

Comment: There are a lot of flaws with the latest versions of Izpack. For instance, the my uninstallers don't work. There are also a lot of little cosmetic issues that make it look less-than-professional. It does seem like it is very close to being quite good, and I'd love to contribute by making it better, but I just don't think it's good for people to expect it to be rock solid out of the box right now.

Comment: @n8n8baby: it was rock-solid for me. "My uninstallers don't work" is not exactly a flaw, you know. However, as you can see, I was using it quite long ago. Maybe it changed.

Comment: Yes, previous versions worked quite well, including uninstallers. The new version 5 has multiple problems. Even old versions had an amateurish look-and-feel, and it is even more amateurish with the small bugs currently in 5. (In its defense, it is RC3, not "final").

Comment: My advice would be that, if being free is important to you, and you have time to contribute to the project, and you need JVM installed anyway (or are not targeting Windows), it may suit your needs. Personally, I found InstallBuilder does exactly what I want, very easily, without JVM requirement, and in a much more polished, native feel for each platform. It is not free, but I spent a day evaluating it and integrating it in parallel with our Izpack builds in Maven, and it seems very capable and easy to use.

Comment: Well, you may have noticed that the answer is 2 years old and the question is not even mine.

Comment: I noticed. I will answer the question directly after I fully evaluate InstallBuilder.

Comment: IzPack sucks because it requires Java. This is a hell in macOS.

Answer (score 3):

After fully integrating both Izpack and InstallBuilder into our builds (using Windows, OSX, and Ubuntu 14 build servers for testing purposes), I will say I believe InstallBuilder is well worth the money (and free for open source projects according to wojciechka).

Izpack is a bit slow, a bit large if you need to package a JVM, and has an amateurish user interface. Version 5 (release candidate 3) was also not generating uninstallers properly. That said, as long as you use a 4.x version and require a JVM anyway, it may be enough for your needs. The extension interface is not terribly easy to deal with, but is almost infinitely flexible. The Windows installers do not register with the Control Panel uninstaller list.

InstallBuilder has a great, fast UI in the produced installers and has a serviceable UI for creating installers. The XML is pretty easy to deal with, too. Downloads are about as small as possible. It also includes nice hooks for doing all sorts of custom stuff easily. The only slightly annoying thing I ran into was that the Windows server required that I manually add some configuration to set executable bits on the other systems' packages (other systems didn't require this configuration).

Note: I was using the three-platform version of standard InstallBuilder (not InstallBuilder for QT).