# use lua to make an installer

Tags: lua, installation

I'm looking at trying to make a cross platform installer and I'm curious about using lua to do it, does this sound reasonable to do and if it is I'm hoping someone can point me to a guide to get me started because all I'm finding is "how to install lua"

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "using lua to make a cross platform installer"?

If you expect to write a single system agnostic version of the code, you're out of luck.

If you really need some interaction with the operating system beyond copying/extracting files to unprotected regions, you're going to need to use the system api specific to the system. You can use lua extensions to interact with those apis, search "lua  api". But it is unlikely that interfaces of different os apis are same. You'd have to write quite bit of the platform-specific code.

Generally, this problem is solved by using particular framework, not by choosing particular language.
[Cross Platform Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557441/cross-platform-installer)

Comment: I'm just looking for good scripting language that I can share as much code base as possible.. I do understand much will need to be platform specific